# EJB remote calls through Apache

Tags: java, apache, ejb, remoting, mod-proxy

I am trying to configure remote EJB calls from a remote client to the server.

Configurations:

Client:

```
final Properties jndiProps = new Properties();
jndiProps.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.wildfly.naming.client.WildFlyInitialContextFactory");
jndiProps.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "https://79.117.107.241:443/");
jndiProps.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, ClientSession.instance().getUsername());
jndiProps.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, ClientSession.instance().getPassword());
final InitialContext context = new InitialContext(jndiProps);
final C businessServiceLoaded = (C) context.lookup(jndiName);
servicesCache.put(jndiName, businessServiceLoaded);
context.close();
return businessServiceLoaded;
```

Server:
Apache/2.4.37 (centos) - running as frontent. I am trying to route the communication to Wildfly throught Apache
/etc/httpd/conf.d/server-le-ssl.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName www.danutcloud.go.ro
ServerAlias danutcloud.go.ro
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
ErrorLog /var/www/log/error.log
CustomLog /var/www/log/requests.log combined

ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8081/

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15552000; includeSubDomains"
</IfModule>

SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/danutcloud.go.ro/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/danutcloud.go.ro/privkey.pem
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

wildfly-16.0.0.Final - running the ear

NOTE: Calling http-remoting://192.168.0.100:8081/(server's internal address) from a different computer on the same network as the server works. Calling https://79.117.107.241:443/(server's public address) gives the following error:

```
    javax.ejb.EJBException: java.io.IOException: WFHTTP000004: Invalid response type text/html;version=-1
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:207)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:112)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy14.loggedUser(Unknown Source)
    at ro.linic.session.BusinessDelegate.login(BusinessDelegate.java:75)
    at ro.linic.session.ClientSession.login(ClientSession.java:45)
    at ro.linic.dialogs.LoginDialog.okPressed(LoginDialog.java:166)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.buttonPressed(Dialog.java:469)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.lambda$0(Dialog.java:622)
    at org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionListener$1.widgetSelected(SelectionListener.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:252)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4131)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1055)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3944)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3547)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:823)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:799)
    at ro.linic.E4LifeCycle.postContextCreate(E4LifeCycle.java:101)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invokeUsingClass(InjectorImpl.java:320)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invoke(InjectorImpl.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.invoke(ContextInjectionFactory.java:147)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.lambda$0(E4Application.java:246)
    at java.util.Optional.ifPresent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createE4Workbench(E4Application.java:242)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.start(E4Application.java:153)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:400)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:661)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1476)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1449)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: WFHTTP000004: Invalid response type text/html;version=-1
    at org.wildfly.httpclient.common.HttpTargetContext$1$1.lambda$completed$4(HttpTargetContext.java:224)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```